# How to create root folder for team project

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfs-2015, source-control-explorer, team-project

I wanted to delete version control for a team project so I could restart with a new solution. I used ts destroy command to delete everything. But now I don't have a root folder anymore in my source control for an existing team project.

I don't want to delete the team project and remake it because it has various tasks , backlogs, etc..

How can I remake the root folder for my team project So I can add my solution to source control ?

Any help is much appreciated! Thx.

Comment: Do you mean you have destroyed a team project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destroy action cannot be reversed. If you want to clean up version control systems, we recommend that you first [delete the files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders) you want to destroy. After you delete the files you can synchronize the Team Foundation warehouse. Otherwise, the warehouse will not be synchronized with the destroyed items.

If you don't have backup of your database, and you have destroyed your team project, you have to create a new one. The destroyed team project cannot be reversed. If you have database backup, you can restore it to get everything back.

Comment: Luckily I have a backup and I restored everything. Now I just deleted all the files under the team project without deleting the root folder.